# how to add a category and subcategory to a woocommerce product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a plugin to add a product to woocommerce 
and `$th1` is the category , `$sth1` is the subcategory.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 wp_set_object_terms( $post_id,$th1->$sth1,'product_cat');
```

I want add the product to the category and the subcategory.
how can i do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have the `term_id`'s for your categories (i.e with `get_term_by`), you can do:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, [$category->term_id, $sub_category->term_id], 'product_cat');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add product ID to table term_relationships. For this, you will need to have "term_taxonomy_id" from "term_taxonomy" table.

So here, in term_relationships object_id = product ID AND term_taxonomy_id found from term_taxonomy table.

You can assign any category/subcategory to product this way.